# Как поменять цвет текста в WordPress в отзывах в textarea

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Не пойму в каком файле нужно заменить черный color на белый.
Т.к. если писать текст в форму - то сейчас черный текст на черном фоне - не видно.
Движок WordPress, шаблон WoodMart.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В файле `style.css` дочерней темы пропишите нужные Вам стили, либо в Apperance -> Customizer -> Additional styles. Ну либо в опциях Вашей темы тоже должен быть пункт для кастомных стилей.

Comment: @Simon, Можете подсказать как именно прописать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в файл `style.css` **дочерней** темы:

```
.woodmart-dark textarea {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Это в файл style.css добавить?)

Comment: Ну разумеется. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое!